# How to combine test results from two different nosetests?

Tags: xml, jenkins, nose, nosetests

I need to run nosetests on 2 packages seperately. For example:

```
nosetests --with-xunit --xunit-file=sample.xml test_sample.py
```

and

```
nosetests --with-xunit --xunit-file=sample1.xml test_sample1.py
```

Now how can I combine sample.xml and sample1.xml files?

Is there any command to do that? I need a combined test result file in xml so that I can use that file in jenkins configuration.

Answer (score 7):

You can have multiple test result (`sample.xml` and `sample1.xml`) in jenkins. Just set `Publish JUnit test result report\Test report XMLs` to select all xml reports with  `**/*.xml`, and generate your xml output within your workspace, something like:

```
nosetests --with-xunit --xunit-file=%WORKSPACE%\\sample.xml test_sample.py
nosetests --with-xunit --xunit-file=%WORKSPACE%\\sample1.xml test_sample1.py
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [xunitmerge](https://github.com/miki725/xunitmerge) package to do this.

```
xunitmerge sample.xml sample1.xml merged.xml
```